# PInvoke SLAPI Functions

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm trying to use some functions in SLAPI but I'm fairly new to PInvoke and I'm really struggling with this. Take SLGetPKeyInformation for example:

```
HRESULT WINAPI SLGetPKeyInformation(
  _In_            HSLC       hSLC,
  _In_      const SLID       *pPKeyId,
  _In_            PCWSTR     pwszValueName,
  _Out_opt_       SLDATATYPE *peDataType,
  _Out_           UINT       *pcbValue,
  _Out_           PBYTE      *ppbValue
);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh971173(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't understand what the HSLC type is, would someone be able to provide sample code for using this function in C#?

Comment: You can get it from [`SLOpen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh971187(v=vs.85).aspx). Note I know nothing about SLAPI, just how to navigate typical Win32 API families ;-)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you, @PeterTorr-MSFT and John Saunders!

Answer (score 3):

HSLC is defined in slpublic.h as:

```
typedef PVOID HSLC;
```

So it can be treated just like any anonymous handle type in winapi and passed around C# code as an IntPtr.